# what would be the best approch to creating a VST MIDI Tone generator Plugin

Tags: midi, vst

Hi this is more of an experiment than a very serious project Idea.

I have downloaded the VST3 API from Steinberg and managed to get it to compile for both windows and mac.

most of the examples that comes with the API are effects which is all good but what I would like to try and achieve is to create a small (8 track) Sequence that outputs midi messages while synced to the midi in clock a bit like the MSQ700 I used in the mid 80's.

I would have thought this would be quite a simple task and shouldn't require and other frameworks like JUCE.

My Question is "is there any sample code out there that demonstrates how to output midi notes in a VST INSTRUMENT plugin. and should it even be an instrument plugin or is there a way to create a VST MIDI Insert plugin ?

I know there are ways to achieve simular results using my pen tool in the Piano roll but that is not the point there was some extra creativity/fun I got when I was composing with Sequencers like the MSQ

Comment: The VST SDK comes with docs. If I remember correctly it talks about some of the most common interactions between host and plugin.